# How useless can the Mayer-Vietoris sequence be in general?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

In an algebraic topology course I'm taking we are often asked to compute the homology groups of a space $X = A \cup B$ using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, and it happens in all of the examples I've seen so far that it's possible to do this without knowing anything about the connecting homomorphisms $\partial_{\ast}$ (say on the level of chains); we only end up needing $H_{\ast}(A), H_{\ast}(B), H_{\ast}(A \cap B)$ and possibly some of the inclusion maps.

My guess is that this is not a typical situation; is there a relatively simple example of a nice space $X$ and nice subspaces $A, B$ such that knowing $H_{\ast}(A), H_{\ast}(B), H_{\ast}(A \cap B)$ is not enough to compute $H_{\ast}(X)$ without knowing the specific form of the connecting homomorphisms? (For maximal relevance to the course $X, A, B, A \cap B$ should be finite simplicial complexes.)

Comment: any situation where the homologies of A,B, A intesrsect B are not trivial I am thinking of S2#S2 for instance

Comment: @El Moro: some of the examples I'm referring to have that property and you still don't need to know what $\partial_{\ast}$ is in advance. Can you work out an example more specifically?

Comment: @Yuan I have to admit that I haven't met that case either before although it seems that the delta map comes from snake lemma so you can have its form from there. It is initially a map of chains that goes down to be a map of homologies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given a long exact sequence

$$ \cdots \to C_{i+1} \to A_i \to B_i \to C_i \to A_{i-1} \to \cdots $$

let the map $A_i \to B_i$ be denoted $f_i$.  Then you have that $C_i$ is an extension

$$ 0 \to coker(f_i) \to C_i \to ker(f_{i-1}) \to 0$$

so up to that extension problem, the maps $f_i$ always determine the $C_i$ groups.  So if you want a situation where the group $C_i$ is ambiguous, you could have $ker(f_{i-1}) = \mathbb Z_2$ and $coker(f_i) = \mathbb Z$, that way $C_i$ could be either $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2$.

Regardless, the connecting map $\partial_i : C_i \to A_{i-1}$ is determined by this extension problem, and it's easy enough to cook up examples either-way.

So I'm a little confused as to the nature of your question. I guess what I'm saying is that you *are* in the typical situation, and Grigory's example is also typical in that it's the inclusion map that makes the differences between his examples.

Regarding how useful/useless the MVS is for a typical problem, it really depends on how easily-expressible your space is as a union of spaces you understand (and their intersections).  If your space doesn't fit that profile, you've got potentially a lot of work to do.  The Serre Spectral Sequence of a Fibration is in a sense something of a souped-up Mayer-Vietoris sequence, and there are plenty of papers where people are happy just computing the $E_3$-page, or determining which page the SS collapses on, or computing a differential.  These extension issues tend to be very thorny and consume much literature.

Comment: I phrased the question in what is in hindsight a somewhat confusing way; I think the current edit is closer to what I meant.

Comment: ...and extra +1 for the point "(iterated) M-V = SSS"

Comment: Yes, the map from $A$ to $B$ determines $C$ up to extension (so if you are over a field, everything is unique), but (1) there is still an extension problem and (2) understanding the maps can be a subtle matter.  In particular, in the example that Grigory gave, the inclusions are "the same" in both cases, it's just that the gluing is twisted by a homeomorphism.  Put differently, knowing $H_*(A\cap B)\to H_* (A)$ and $H_*(A\cap B)\to H_* (B)$ up to automorphisms does not give $H_*(A\cap B)\to H_* (A)\oplus H_* (A).$

Comment: @Aaron: thank you, that is more or less what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 11):

Knowing only $H(A)$, $H(B)$ and $H(A\cap B)$ is not enough, of course.
For example, taking $A=B=S^1\times D^2$ and gluing them by $S^1\times S^1=A\cap B$ one can get either $X_1=S^2\times S^1$ or $X_2=S^3$. This gives two Mayer-Vietoris sequences with identical $H(A)$, $H(B)$ and $H(A\cap B)$ but different H(X).

As for the situation where one also knows inclusion maps, see Ryan Budney's excellent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40715/how-useless-can-the-mayer-vietoris-sequence-be-in-general/40727#40727).

Comment: This construction can be generalized: take some non-trivial bundle $X\to \Sigma B$ that restricts trivially on B etc. (Example above corresponds to the Hopf fibration.)